# New Parser with NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, parsing, nsxmlparser

Now i can parser xml like this:

```
<root>
     <name>Alberto</name>
     <subname>Martin</subname>
     <age>58</age>
</root>
```

But now i need parser some like it:

```
 <root>
     <name>Alberto</name>
     <subname>Martin</subname>
     <age>58</age>
     <sons>
          <son>
               <name>Pablo</name>
               <subname>Martin</subname>
          </son>
          <son>
               <name>Pablo</name>
               <subname>Martin</subname>
          </son>
     </sons>
 </root>
```

To do the second part, what is the best form?

At the moment, to parser the first part im use NSXMLParser with the 3 methods, but to parser with "child" i dont know do it...

Can someone help me?

Thanks for all friend.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you start by reading Apple's documentation on [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html)

I also found this tutorial with a quick Google search [XML Parser tutorial](http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/2008/07/23/make-nsxmlparser-your-friend.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to use NSXMLParser and flexible enough to use the LibXML here is the [help](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).